# What is the intuition behind $R= (\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z})[X] /\lt X^3 + \bar2 X^2 + X + \bar1 \gt $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-group

I am studying ring theory and am looking at quotient rings. I have seen this example of a quotient ring: $$R= (\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z})[X] /\langle X^3 + \bar2 X^2 + X + \bar1 \rangle $$

I believe that $\bar2=2+3\Bbb{Z}$ and $\bar1=1+3\Bbb{Z}$, but I can't get my head around what this ring R means.

Can anyone help with the intuition?

How can I check if this ring is commutative or unital?

Comment: While it is true, I wouldn't think of $\bar{2}$ as $2 + 3\mathbb{Z}$, I don't think it will help your intuition. It's better, imo, to think of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as the remainders of integers when you divide them by $3$. Which makes them more like regular numbers, which are easier to think about.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than $<, >$ does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show a simpler example:

$$R= (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})[X] /\langle X^2 + \bar1 \rangle $$

Before the quotient, we have all polyonomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$. But the quotient tells us that we can replace $X^2$ with $-\bar1$ (which, because we're working in integers mod 2, is the same as $\bar 1$). So a polynomial like
$$
x^4 + x^3 + x
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
(x^2)^2 + x^2(x) + x = (\bar1)^2 + \bar1 x + x = \bar1 + x + x = \bar1
$$
I can do this rewriting because there's only one relation, and it's nice and simple. But in general, a quotient like this allows you to "simplify away" any terms of power higher than $k$ (where $k$ is the largest exponent in the quotiented polynomial) by replacing them with one or more terms of power lower than $k$. (This is a little bit like "casting out nines", if you learned to do that when you were learning arithmetic; if not, ignore this remark.)

Pro tip: when you want to write angle-brackets, us `\langle ... \rangle` instead of `\lt ... \gt`.

Comment: how does the quotient tell us we can replace $X^2 with -\bar1$?

Comment: In the quotient, $X^2 + 1$ (and all multiples of it) are in the same coset as $0$, so we can write $0 \sim X^2 + 1$ as a shorthand; subtracting $1$ from both sides gives $-1 \sim X^2$. Put differently, $X^2$ is in the same coset as $X^2 + (-1)(X^2 + 1)$, which is the same as $X^2 - X^2 - 1$, which is the same as $-1$, so $X^2$ and $-1$ are in the same coset, so $\overline{X^2}$ and $\overline{-1}$ denote the same coset. It's the same way that you know that $8$ and $1$ are in the same coset in mod-$7$ arithmetic: you can subtract a multiple of $7$ from $8$ to get $1$.

Comment: That makes so much more sense now. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. It's rare that I get to answer an abstract-algebra question, so it was a pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

$R \cong \mathbb F_3[u]$ where $u^3+2u^2+u+1=0$. In words, polynomials expressions in $u$ with coefficients in the integers mod $3$ and subject to that relation. So, quadratic expressions in $u$.

Compare with $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb R[i]$ with $i^2+1=0$.

Comment: I think explicitly writing out $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ makes the analogy clearer for this level

Comment: @OsamaGhani, yes, thanks!